# How can I connect my Clash of Clans village to my Google Play account on a Nokia XL?

Tags: clash-of-clans, android

When I try to connect to Google Play, it would say "download Google play service". After I downloaded it, it says that it is "not supported by your device, please contact the manufacturer".

Comment: Try contacting the manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Supercell](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?p=web&f=i-lost-my-village-how-do-i-get-it-back&s=lost-village) (the developer of the game), the following devices are not supported (they don't support and come with the Google Apps Package, including Google Play, by default):

> Blackberry, Nokia X-Series, Kindle HD...

Short of [rooting your phone to allow installation of the Google Play app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/86811/33031), I believe there's not much you can do about this. You might also want to see this post in Android SE on possible solutions: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/33031)

Comment: "Short of rooting your phone to allow installation" confuses me. I had a similar problem, and was able to install the play store to my phone without any rooting what so ever. Gae me full access to the play store..

Comment: @Timelord64 What's your phone? Is it also a Nokia XL like OP's?

Comment: it was actually a no-named brand. Being a Nokia XL should not make a differance, which I assume is why the question you link was closed as a duplicate of an identical question concerning all android devices

Comment: @Timelord64 Actually, the brand matters. See the two linked posts to Android SE in my answer on why. Not all Android phones are licensed to use Google services. The Nokia X-Series is *not* licensed to use Google services (Nokia's mobile phone division is Microsoft-owned), so you won't be able to install Google Play in that phone, unless you root it. From the [linked post to Android SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/86824/33031) in my answer: "The Play Services are installed at the /system partition (because they need higher privileges to install and uninstall applications)".

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm not sure why you're confused as I am only referring to OP's case with him using a Nokia XL. If you can install Google Play, then you don't have the same issue as OP.

Comment: Im quite sure it was the same case, with my other phone. It was more of a dud "omg, a smart phone for twenty bucks, lets see what it can do" phone. Ive revoked my downvote until I can chase it up again, but Im quite sure the license thing was still an issue. Perhaps I just got lucky?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30710/discussion-between-galacticninja-and-timelord64).