# If I connected to Facebook will my villages be saved?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In my phone,Google+ app or google play store is an unsupported app. My phone is a Nokia XL. But if I connect to Facebook, will my village be saved?

Comment: Facebook does not support game saving and the Nokia XL does not support Google Apps (which allows you to save, through Google Play). See [How can I connect my Clash of Clans village to my Google Play account on a Nokia XL?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/234180/how-can-i-connect-my-clash-of-clans-village-to-my-google-play-account-on-a-nokia)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get your village on to a different phone there should be a thing in the settings on the game that says something like (Connect a device) or something like that. This lets you put your village on to a different device.